# How to add multiple arcs to globe

Tags: d3.js

I have a simple d3 v4 globe and (with some help from here) have an arc which animates at the end. I wish now to add several arcs from a json file, and have tried manipulating the coordinates, without success.

This is the working code.
https://plnkr.co/edit/ZYM5f1KR1FXiTq1y4n1f?p=preview

I have included a data.json file with sample json data.
My issue is loading and looping through this file.

```
d3.json('data.json')
```

and then I get lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firts, let's nest the two `d3.json` functions:

```
d3.json("https://rawgit.com/mbostock/topojson/master/examples/world-50m.json", function(error, world) {
    d3.json("data.json", function(coord){
    //code here
    });
});
```

That way, we have access to both JSONs simultaneously.

As both `source` and `target` are geo coordinates, we'll change your JSON to:

```
[{"source":[-74, 40],"destination":[37, 55]},
{"source":[20, 50],"destination":[-60, -39]},
{"source":[37, 55],"destination":[32, -15]}, 
//
{"source":[147, -37],"destination":[-80, 37]}]
```

So, each `source` and `destination` have the coordinates as an array.

Then, in your code, we append the paths:

```
var line = svg.selectAll(".paths")
  .data(coord)
  .enter()
  .append("path");
```

Here is your plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/Ax4Tby47lFlryzVWCHi2?p=preview

Comment: This works well (thanks). I can see now how the nesting is working and where I was going awry. If I understand correctly, the json data is picked up by d3 and iterated internally, and the lines are drawn and the landing at .end fires at the completion.  Is it possible, to draw each line seperately? eg: at given intervals, or even from a json request?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but you'll have to write a different transition. As this is another issue, I suggest you post a different question regarding this (drawing lines separately).